# Conflict between table sticky header and popovers

Tags: javascript, css, bootstrap-table

Bootstraptable version(s) affected:
1.18.3

Excuse me，When using table sticky header and popovers, the pop-up frame of popovers will fail. Is there a way to solve it? My code is as follows:

```
<script src="https://cdn.bootcdn.net/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.bootcdn.net/ajax/libs/bootstrap-table/1.18.3/bootstrap-table.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.bootcdn.net/ajax/libs/bootstrap-table/1.18.3/extensions/sticky-header/bootstrap-table-sticky-header.js"></script>
<script>$(function show() {$("[data-toggle='popover']").popover({});})</script>
<script>var $table = $('#table')$(function() {$table.bootstrapTable('destroy').bootstrapTable({stickyHeader: true,})})</script>
<table data-toggle="table" class="table-hover table-striped" id="table" data-toolbar="#toolbar" >...<button id="temp" type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-container="body" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="top" data-content="Top popover">Popover on top</button>...</table>

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong? Thanks
```

Comment: Please provide a codepen page for testing, thanks.

Comment: This is a bootstrapTable('') problem. It has been solved. Thank you.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.